# non-secure short value returning text compressors

Tags: text, encryption, hash, compression

I am in a search of a text compressor that should return short value.

`MD5` is awesome in this way but there is not an easy solution for decryption.

I did try `FNV` and it works great too, but could not find any decryptors.

I am looking for **compressors** rather than **encryptors** so security is not an issue. Although **encryptors** can also be used if they take less computation time and are easy to be decrypted.

A 256 bit value, at the max, returning would be great.

BTW, if you could make a decryptor for this `FNV` encryptor, would be really cool:

```
function fnv32a( str )
{
    var FNV1_32A_INIT = 0x811c9dc5;
    var hval = FNV1_32A_INIT;
    for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i )
    {
        hval ^= str.charCodeAt(i);
        hval += (hval << 1) + (hval << 4) + (hval << 7) + (hval << 8) + (hval << 24);
    }
    return hval >>> 0;
}
```

Comment: The statement "MD5 is awesome..." made me cringe. Sentences that use MD5 should start with "MD5 is broken..." or "MD5 may still be safe to use..." and the latter should end with a statement from your lawyer :) <- sorry, forgot smiley, this is tongue in cheek, not criticism

Answer (score 0):

Hashing by definition is one way. You cannot compress a random message with possibly infinite length into a finite length encoding. Hashing is not encryption either. So you are asking a question that - by definition - has no positive answer.